Why is a Non-Homogenous Poisson Process more complicated than a Homogeneous Poisson Process?
Last week in my class, my professor mentioned that estimating the parameters of a Non-Homogenous Poisson Process is significantly more difficult compared to estimating the parameters of a Homogenous Poisson Process.
I am trying to figure out why this is: Why is a Non-Homogenous Poisson Process more complicated than a Homogeneous Poisson Process?
Here is my analysis:
Homogenous Poisson Process
In a homogeneous Poisson process, events occur at a constant rate $λ$ over time.

Probability of n events in interval [0, T]:

For a homogeneous Poisson process, the probability of observing n events in an interval of length T is given by the Poisson distribution:
$$ P(N(T) = n) = \frac{(\lambda T)^n e^{-\lambda T}}{n!} $$

Joint distribution of event times:

Given that $n$ events occurred, their occurrence times $t₁, t₂, ..., tₙ$ ( ordered) follow a uniform distribution on $[0, T]$. The joint density of these ordered times is:
$$ f(t_1, t_2, ..., t_n | n) = \frac{n!}{T^n} $$
Combining everything together, the likelihood is the joint probability of observing $n$ events and their specific times:
$$ L(\lambda) = P(N(T) = n) \cdot f(t_1, t_2, ..., t_n | n) $$
$$ = \frac{(\lambda T)^n e^{-\lambda T}}{n!} \cdot \frac{n!}{T^n} $$
$$ = \lambda^n e^{-\lambda T} $$
Therefore, the likelihood function for a homogeneous Poisson process is:
$$ L(\lambda) = \lambda^n e^{-\lambda T} $$
$$ \log L(\lambda) = n \log(\lambda) - \lambda T $$
Non-Homogenous Poisson Process:
For a non-homogeneous Poisson process, the probability of observing $n$ events in an interval $[0, T]$ is the same as above, but with a rate function  $Λ(T)$:
$$ P(N(T) = n) = \frac{(\Lambda(T))^n e^{-\Lambda(T)}}{n!} $$
Suppose we assume that the rate function $Λ(T)$ has the following form:
$$ \Lambda(T) = \int_0^T \lambda(t) dt = \int_0^T \alpha e^{\beta t} dt = \frac{\alpha}{\beta}(e^{\beta T} - 1) $$
We still need to write the joint density of times. Given that $n$ events occurred at times $t₁, t₂, ..., tₙ$, their joint density should be proportional to the product of the rate function at each time:
$$ f(t_1, t_2, ..., t_n | n) \propto \prod_{i=1}^n \lambda(t_i) = \prod_{i=1}^n \alpha e^{\beta t_i} $$
We just need to add a  normalizing constant ensures that this density integrates to 1 over all possible orderings of $n$ points in $[0, T]$. The normalizing factor is $n! / Λ(T)ⁿ$.
So, the full joint density is:
$$ f(t_1, t_2, ..., t_n | n) = \frac{n!}{\Lambda(T)^n} \prod_{i=1}^n \lambda(t_i) = \frac{n!}{\Lambda(T)^n} \prod_{i=1}^n \alpha e^{\beta t_i} $$
Combining everything together, the likelihood is the joint probability of observing $n$ events and their specific times:
$$ L(\alpha, \beta) = P(N(T) = n) \cdot f(t_1, t_2, ..., t_n | n) $$
$$ = \frac{(\Lambda(T))^n e^{-\Lambda(T)}}{n!} \cdot \frac{n!}{\Lambda(T)^n} \prod_{i=1}^n \alpha e^{\beta t_i} $$
$$ L(\alpha, \beta) = e^{-\Lambda(T)} \prod_{i=1}^n \alpha e^{\beta t_i} $$
$$ L(\alpha, \beta) = \exp\left(-\frac{\alpha}{\beta}(e^{\beta T} - 1)\right) \prod_{i=1}^n \alpha e^{\beta t_i} $$
$$ \log L(\alpha, \beta) = -\frac{\alpha}{\beta}(e^{\beta T} - 1) + n\log(\alpha) + \beta \sum_{i=1}^n t_i $$
After all this work, I can see that the likelihood is more complicated in the Non-Homogenous case. Is this correct?

Supporting Proof 1: Derivation of $P(N(T) = n)$ in a homogeneous Poisson process
In a homogenous poisson process, we typically assume:

The number of events in non-overlapping intervals are independent.
The probability of more than one event occurring at exactly the same instant is negligible.

For a very small interval $Δt$, the probability of exactly one event occurring is approximately $λΔt$, where $λ$ is the rate parameter.
$$ P(\text{1 event in Δt}) ≈ λΔt $$
$$ P(\text{0 events in Δt}) ≈ 1 - λΔt $$
$$ P(\text{>1 event in Δt}) ≈ 0 \text{ (negligible for small Δt)} $$
Let $m = T/Δt$, so each subinterval has length $Δt$.
Now for the Probability of $n$ events in $T$. This is equivalent to having $n$ subintervals with an event and $(m-n)$ subintervals without an event, in any order.
$$ P(N(T) = n) = \binom{m}{n} (λΔt)^n (1-λΔt)^{m-n} $$
Take the limit as $m → ∞$ (or $Δt → 0$):}
$$ \lim_{m→∞} P(N(T) = n) = \lim_{m→∞} \frac{m!}{n!(m-n)!} (λT/m)^n (1-λT/m)^{m-n} $$
$$ = \lim_{m→∞} \frac{m(m-1)...(m-n+1)}{m^n} · \frac{(λT)^n}{n!} · (1-λT/m)^m · (1-λT/m)^{-n} $$
Evaluate the limits (the second one uses a well known limit identity):

$\lim_{m→∞} \frac{m(m-1)...(m-n+1)}{m^n} = 1$
$\lim_{m→∞} (1-λT/m)^m = e^{-λT}$
$\lim_{m→∞} (1-λT/m)^{-n} = 1$

Combining these results:
$$ P(N(T) = n) = \frac{(λT)^n}{n!} e^{-λT} $$

Supporting Proof 2: Derivation of the formula for the joint density of event times in a homogeneous Poisson process, given that $n$ events have occurred in the interval $[0, T]$.
$$ f(t_1, t_2, ..., t_n | n) = \frac{n!}{T^n} $$
The key thing to remember here is that for the $n$ events in $[0, T]$, their occurrence times are uniformly distributed over this interval.
If we don't consider the order of events, each event time $tᵢ$ is independently and uniformly distributed over $[0, T]$. The probability density for each $tᵢ$ is:
$$ f(t_i) = \frac{1}{T}, \quad 0 \leq t_i \leq T $$
Now for the Joint density of unordered times. Since the events are independent, the joint density of unordered times is the product of their individual densities:
$$ f_{unordered}(t_1, t_2, ..., t_n | n) = \frac{1}{T} · \frac{1}{T} · ... · \frac{1}{T} = \frac{1}{T^n} $$
However, we typically observe the ordered times: $t₁ < t₂ < ... < tₙ$. The number of ways to order $n$ events is $n!$.
The density of ordered times is $n!$ times the density of unordered times, because each set of ordered times corresponds to $n!$ different sets of unordered times.
$$ f_{ordered}(t_1, t_2, ..., t_n | n) = n! · f_{unordered}(t_1, t_2, ..., t_n | n) $$
Substituting the unordered density:
$$ f(t_1, t_2, ..., t_n | n) = n! · \frac{1}{T^n} = \frac{n!}{T^n} $$

Supporting Proof 3: Proving
$$ \lim_{m \to \infty} \left(1 - \frac{\lambda T}{m}\right)^m = e^{-\lambda T} $$
Let $x = \lambda T$, and $n = m$. Our limit becomes:
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 - \frac{x}{n}\right)^n $$
The well-known limit definition of $e$:
$$ e = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n $$
Raise both sides to the power of $-x$, we get:
$$ e^{-x} = \left[\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right]^{-x} $$
Move the exponent inside the limit:
$$ e^{-x} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{-nx} $$
Let $y = -nx$. As $n$ approaches infinity, $y$ will also approach infinity (assuming $x$ is positive). So we can rewrite our limit as:
$$ e^{-x} = \lim_{y \to -\infty} \left(1 - \frac{x}{y}\right)^y $$
$$ e^{-x} = \lim_{y \to \infty} \left(1 - \frac{x}{y}\right)^y $$
Replacing $y$ with $n$ and $x$ with $\lambda T$, we get back to our original expression:
$$ e^{-\lambda T} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 - \frac{\lambda T}{n}\right)^n $$
This proves that:
$$ \lim_{m \to \infty} \left(1 - \frac{\lambda T}{m}\right)^m = e^{-\lambda T} $$

I admittedly didn't read your whole post (it was quite long) but the basic idea is that for a homogenous Poisson process, you're only estimating one parameter. When you're given a general rate function, this could be some infinite-dimensional object (like it depends on infinitely many parameters, if it's an arbitrary function), which makes it much more difficult (potentially impossible, depending on your metric) object to estimate.

thank you so much! I think I got the main idea....

no problem! The main idea is that if you have some non-homogeneous Poisson process, let's say it's piecewise constant with $k$ different pieces, then you need like $k$ times as many data points in order to estimate each parameter accurately
